# Django 3.2.6 | Admin | get_form() | Modify Form Field | Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'base_fields'

Tags: django, forms, django-queryset, admin, python-3.8

I am customizing my Django Admin forms to modify a form field queryset.
The below code works on some of my Models but not others.

The only differences between the models is the name as they all have the same fields:

```
Club = models.ForeignKey('configuration.Club', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
Title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
Description = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
```

**Code that throughs an exception (Trophy)**

Model:

```
class Trophy(models.Model):
    Club = models.ForeignKey('configuration.Club', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=360, blank=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Title', 'Club']
        unique_together = ['Title', 'Club']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

Admin:

```
class TrophyView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'Club', 'Title', 'Description')

    #Modify Form
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        #Get User's Profile >> Club
        user = request.user
        profile = vMemberDetails.objects.get(username=user.username)
        club = profile.Club_pk
        clubID = Club.objects.filter(id=club)
    
        #Super
        form = super(TrophyView, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['Club'].queryset = clubID
 
    #Modify View
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        user = request.user
        profile = vMemberDetails.objects.get(username=user.username)
        club = profile.Club_pk
        clubID = Club.objects.get(id=club)
        profiles = vMemberDetails.objects.filter(Club_pk=clubID.pk)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else: 
            return qs.filter(Club=clubID.pk) | qs.filter(Club__isnull=True)
        
admin.site.register(Trophy,TrophyView)
```

When I **print(form.base_fields)**:

```
{'Club': django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x000001E3895D6AF0, 
'Title': django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x000001E3895D6A60, 
'Description':django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x000001E3895D6D30}
```

When I **print(form.base_fields['Club'].queryset)**:

```
QuerySet [Club: Test_001 Club, Club: Test_002]
```

Exception 'NoneType' object has no attribute **'base_fields'**:

```
AttributeError at /admin/configuration/trophy/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'base_fields'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/configuration/trophy/add/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'base_fields'
Python Version: 3.8.11
```

---

**Code that returns a modified querset against a similar Model (Target)**

Model:

```
class Target(models.Model):
    Club = models.ForeignKey('configuration.Club', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Title']
        unique_together = ['Title', 'Club']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

Admin:

```
class TargetView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'Club', 'Title', 'Description')

    #Modify Form
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        profile = vMemberDetails.objects.get(username=user.username)
        club = profile.Club_pk
        clubID = Club.objects.filter(id=club)

        #Super
        form = super(TargetView, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['Club'].queryset = clubID
        return form

    #Modify View
    def get_queryset(self, request):

        #Get User's Profile >> Club
        qs = super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        user = request.user
        profile = vMemberDetails.objects.get(username=user.username)
        club = profile.Club_pk
        clubID = Club.objects.get(id=club)
        profiles = vMemberDetails.objects.filter(Club_pk=clubID.pk)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else: 
            return qs.filter(Club=clubID.pk) | qs.filter(Club__isnull=True)
        
admin.site.register(Target,TargetView)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you find any solution for this [@kristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14877924/kristopher)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `return form` in `get_form()` method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).